# Cocoapods in Flutter: different prefix: "/" and "Pods" (ArgumentError)

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I am using a project that was created a while ago. The iOS config is resulting impossible. After being able to adjust every necessary thing on Xcode (flavors, RunnerTests, etc), I am getting an error related to cocoapods that I have not been able to go around.

Main errors are:

> .../cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding':
> **can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)**

> .../Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/pathname.rb:522:in
> `relative_path_from': **different prefix: "/" and "Pods" (ArgumentError)**

Everything installs perfectly until a point where this happens:

```
   Integrating client project

   Integrating target `Pods-Runner` (`Runner.xcodeproj` project)
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

Error output from CocoaPods:

    .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `report'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/pathname.rb:522:in `relative_path_from': different prefix: "/" and "Pods" (ArgumentError)
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:162:in `create_xcconfig_ref'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:45:in `set_target_xcconfig'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in integrate'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:20:in `each'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:20:in `block in integrate'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:19:in `each'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:19:in `integrate'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator.rb:561:in `block in integrate!'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator.rb:560:in `integrate!'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:146:in `each'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:146:in `integrate_user_targets'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:73:in `integrate!'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:929:in `block in integrate_user_project'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:925:in `integrate_user_project'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:185:in `integrate'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:170:in `install!'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from .../.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I have tried to install the cocoapods in every way possible: using brew, using sudo and using ruby (rbenv). I don't know if the error has to do with a wrong installation, or a wrong configuration of the project itself (it has been proven to have very weird configurations before for other things). I am also not experienced with any of this so I don't know where to look.
Could you please help me?

**UPDATE**

Found new information: I am not able to find the Podfile.lock.
I found this in a Podfile of firebase_core. There is a folder .symlinks with some firebase pods there.

```
  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  ephemeral_dir = File.join('Flutter', 'ephemeral')
  symlink_dir = File.join(ephemeral_dir, '.symlinks')
  symlink_plugins_dir = File.join(symlink_dir, 'plugins')
  system("rm -rf #{symlink_dir}")
  system("mkdir -p #{symlink_plugins_dir}")
```

Comment: Did you try running 'sudo gem update xcodeproj'

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic Gems already up-to-date: xcodeproj